# calculate orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus, orthogonality

Given matrix $A(m\times n)$

find matrix  $B(n\times m)$ that fulfill the equation

$A\,B=0\,(m\times m)$ mean orthogonal

m less then n

Comment: Wha have you donc?

Comment: I use maple program for smal matrix. I have nxm equations for nxm unknowns. But this can not be the best solution? I haven’t study mathematic, I am engineer.

Comment: Is m>n or the converse? Some assumptions are necessary. Without any assumption it is difficult to propose anything else than A=0 as a solution to AB=0, but I am not convinced that this solution suits you.

Comment: I just corrected m is less then n !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $A^+$ (the pseudoinverse of $A$) to construct the ($n\times n$) nullspace projector
$$P = I_n - A^+A$$
The key property of this projector is 
$$AP = (A-AA^+A) = (A-A) = 0$$
Now any ($n\times m$) matrix $C$ can be used to construct the required matrix
$$B = PC$$
**NB:**  For $m\ge n,\,$ $A^+A=I\,$ and therefore $P=0\,$ and $B=0$.